# Convert two-column table into four-column page seperated table

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

I have a two-column table which contains foreign words in one column and its translation in the other column. This list/table is very long (740 rows, which will vary) and currently is in an excel file. For example:

[image]

I want to create a printable version of this. If I move this to a Word file and print it the way it is, I'll be wasting the space on the right. So, instead of a two-column table, I want to use a four-column table. But this isn't easy to prepare. What I really want is something like this:

[image]

Basically, it should follow this ordering:

[image]

How can I achieve this using Excel or Word? I can also use another software as long as it gets the job done.

---

<sub>I've already created the desired table in Word manually, but this takes very long and is painful. I'll be creating new lists and I don't really want to convert each list manually. I need a way to automate this process.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Microsoft Word, you could layout your document in two columns, basically achieve the same results, see example below. The easiest way to achieve this is to select (Ctrl+A) the whole table/document, then select the 2 column option under the Column-icon in the Layout ribbon menu.

[image: Screenshot]

If you set the column gap to zero it will look the same as your example (with no gap between the cells).

However, this solution will not treat the table as a four column table, if you specifically wanted to achieve that.

Comment: Columns were used just for layout purposes. Tried this method and this two column layout seems better. So I'll take it :)